# Read data from HTTP PUT

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, http-put

I am currently implementing a RESTful web service which talks XML using [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) and REST by [Phil Sturgeon](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/). I am now stuck at how to read XML from HTTP PUT. This is what I did.

At the client side:

```
$(function(){
    // Bind a click event to the 'ajax' object id
    $("#new_user").click(function(evt){
        // JavaScript needs totake over. So stop the browser from redirecting the page
        evt.preventDefault();
        var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml><name>'+$("#txtname").val()+'</name><email>'+$("#txtemail").val()+'</email></xml>';

        // Ajax request to get the data
        $.ajax({
            // URL from the link that was clicked on
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
                        type: "put",
                        contentType: "application/xml",
                        processData: false,
                        data: str,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                //alert('Successful AJAX request!');
                                   //var items = parseXml(data);
                                   //printXml(items);
            },
            // Failed to load request. This could be caused by any number of problems like server issues, bad links, etc.
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Oh no! A problem with the Ajax request!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

At the server side:

```
public function users_put(){
    $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    print_r($input);
}
```

It prints out nothing. The above JavaScript code and function works well in HTTP POST.

Comment: I think my problem does not lie in client side's code; but instead at server. because I saw this in developer console of Google Chrome:
Request URL:http://test.localhost/index.php/api/usercomp/users/id/1
Request Method:PUT
Request Payload
<xml><name>fdfd</name><email>ffff</email></xml>
So it means, the xml was sent to server successfully. but i just don't know how to read it.

Answer (score 2):

The manual has a good reference for that: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

You cannot handle PUT requests without altering the HTTP daemon's setup.

---

If you're using Apache and have access to mod_rewrite, make a .htaccess file in the root folder that you PUT to with something like:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But the details depend on what HTTP daemon (Apache, IIS, lighttpd, etc) and which PHP framework you use.

Comment: do you mean, i need to enable http put in httpd.conf? if you do mean it, well, it still not works in my case.

Comment: Read the manual page...it explains how quite well. You need to redirect all PUT requests to a PHP script.

Comment: I don't think i should do it because the framework already redirect all http method to the exact handler defined in the class.

Comment: In that case, I'd say use POST instead. PUT will require some mod_rewrite magic at least, and preferably a config change.

Comment: Well, that's quite good idea anyway which i already tested it working. but just a noobie question: so there is no real implementation of http PUT handler in RESTful web service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest discusses that. Both POST and PUT are used, but PUT takes more configuration to get working with PHP.

Comment: are you sure you already read the link you gave me? it is about the definition of POST, PUT, not implementation of the handler for PUT method in server side.

Comment: Please and again please give me the procedure, or script on how to make it work, not something like 'it takes more configuration'....it needs http's daemon's setup....it needs to have a config change,....it requires some mod_rewrite.....Those are not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST. Your application will have to determine if the request is a 'PUT' or not. If you specify the id of the object that you are modifying then you can assume it is a 'PUT' request. I'm not sure how CodeIgniter handles this, but I do know that Zend Framework automatically routes to the putAction when the id is specified. (e.g. /account/5)